# react-native-fbsdk not returning email

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I have integrated the `react-native-fbsdk` library and getting user profile info such as name, middle name etc except email

i have tried `readPermissions={["email,"public_profile","friends"]}`

Then too not getting email

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like it is known global issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016/

Comment: is there is any solution to this ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm facing the same issue and it looks like the only workaround is using the `LoginManager` class provided by `react-native-fbsdk`.

```js
import {
  LoginManager,
} from 'react-native-fbsdk';

const _fbLogin = () => {
  LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
    (result) => {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Login cancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Login success with permissions: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
    }
  );
}
```

And you can try using that `_fbLogin` function as an event handler for a custom button. I did not find how to use it with the blue, out of the box facebook Log in button.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`readPermissions` has now been replaced with `permissions`

```
<LoginButton
          permissions={["email", "user_friends", "public_profile"]}
          onLoginFinished={this._onFacebookLoginFinished.bind(this)}
          onLogoutFinished={this._onFacebookLogoutFinished.bind(this)}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've completed a login and have an access token, you need to use the Graph API https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#graph-api to retrieve data
you can find explaination for it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/280)